# Purple screen only on resume from hibernate

Tags: boot, 13.10, hibernate

This might be a duplicate, apologies if it is... I couldn't find anything exactly identical.

My system boots up just fine. But whenever it tries to resume from hibernation, I get to GRUB and then it hangs on a purple screen. ctrl+alt+F1 doesn't do anything. This problem started in the last week after working perfectly for a year.

In `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` the last entry is a bunch of successes for the sleep.d suspend_hybrid hooks. It seems like it successfully suspended.

In `/var/log/syslog`, I see it tries to boot with:

```
Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=UUID=4666fbf8-118b-4336-bc4b-54c0e7dfd118 ro nosplash nomodeset acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
```

then there's a ton of stuff in the syslog about NetworkManager and a few other things but no real errors.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is but there might be a problem with a new plugin you installed. In Ubuntu 18.10 I had to disable all plugins first to handle similar issue. Could you please try to disable all system tweaks (compiz for Unity, tweaks for gnome). If that doesn't help please let me know and we'll try to come up with something else. Because alternatively, there might be a problem with your swap. Depending if you have swap in partition or in file. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04
Or yet another thing may be, as you're writin