# How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, hibernate

How should I successfully hibernate Ubuntu 16.04?

I've tried almost every solution on the web but non of them was actually helpful.
I found my problem almost completely similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767679/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-shut-down-after-suspend-or-hibernate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Comment: Does `sudo pm-hibernate` work?

Comment: hasn't the situation changed with systemd? now we are meant to use `systemctl hibernate` so perhaps not a dupe... or at least updated answer may be required to make the old question valid to dupe

Comment: What kernel version are you running? Type `uname -r` in the terminal (apologies if you already knew this).

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of  `free`  so we can determine if you have enough swap setup to successfully hibernate.

Comment: @ElderGeek good thing to check. Unfortunately OP hasn't signed on since July 2016. Perhaps he forgot to pay his ISP in Tehran, Iran.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well past performance is no indication of future results. One never knows. Perhaps the OP will drop back in and answer both of our questions. Doubtful as that may seem ATM...

Comment: I just changed to Ubuntu and for me it was as simple as pressing ALT when the shutdown window was open and a _pause_ button appears which puts the machine into hibernate

Comment: None of these worked for me.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  Instead, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/218436) helpful.

Comment: The link to the question `Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't shut down after suspend or hibernate` is misleading. Please delete that link, your question is quite the opposite of that link.

Answer (score 81):

### Hibernation using `systemctl` and getting it working in tough cases

For me, `pm-hibernate` always fails. After some tweaks, I was able to hibernate using the interface of systemd (init system in 16.04 and above). I also managed to get it working on 17.04 with a swap file. This case study may be useful for others with problems.

First try:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

If that fails, begin troubleshooting: in the hibernate state (HTD or ACPI S4) the machine state is written to disk so that no power is needed to preserve it. The state is written either to a swap partition or to a swap file. **Note: if using Btrfs DO NOT attempt to use a swap file as this may cause filesystem corruption**

Your swap partition or swap file may need to be the same size as RAM to allow hibernation, but there is a good chance you will be able to hibernate if it is at least 2/5 the size of RAM, according to [the **Arch wiki page**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#About_swap_partition.2Ffile_size), so try other steps first before increasing swap size.

**If your problem is that you get a clean boot instead of the expected resume, at a minimum you most likely need to set a boot parameter to find the disk image**

Find your swap partition:

```
grep swap /etc/fstab
```

for me this returns (partial output)

```
# swap was on /dev/mmcblk0p3 during installation
```

where `/dev/mmcblk0p3` is the partition to specify

Add a boot parameter:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

To the line starting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add `resume=/dev/YourSwapPartition` to the section in quotes (replace with the the partition you identified earlier). Using my example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mmcblk0p3"
```

Any time you change this file, you must run `sudo update-grub` or the changes will have no effect.

Now you need to reboot. Then you can try to hibernate, by issuing the command:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

To resume, press the power button and the system will boot.

If you still have problems, start debugging.

I include my case below as an example, but detailed information on debugging S states can be found [in this blog](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues) and [also this one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt).

Set some more boot parameters to capture more information. Remove `quiet` and `splash` and add `initcall_debug` and `no_console_suspend` which will cause init system calls to be printed to the console so you can watch what is going wrong. I set this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/dev/mmcblk0p3 no_console_suspend initcall_debug"
```

Which helped me see what was going wrong on resume from hibernation. You can also try using `dmesg`.

In my case, after resume I lost WiFi, and the kernel clearly was upset as most commands (for example reading anything from `/sys`, reloading modules or any `systemctl` command) would not work - the process would appear to start and just hang (all this would be returned to normal after reboot of course). Watching the system very slowly shut down and reading all the debug messages, I noticed that there were a lot of problems with "brcm", so I guessed my Broadcom wireless driver module was to blame. Sure enough I adjusted my hibernation procedure to unload the module first:

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

on resume I reinsert the module

```
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

And everything worked perfectly. I also have to blacklist the `btsdio` module which seems to be incompatible with `brcmfmac`

---

#### Update: Hibernation using a swap file on 17.04.

Once again with help from the Arch wiki page and some additional tinkering, I managed to get hibernation to work on 17.04 with a swap file. This required an additional boot parameter, `resume_offset=n` where n is the first number under `physical_offset` in the output of `sudo filefrag -v /swapfile`:

```
$ sudo filefrag -v /swapfile
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /swapfile is 1425873920 (348114 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..   32767:      34816..     67583:  32768:            
   1:    32768..   63487:      67584..     98303:  30720:            
   ....
```

Therefore, the additional boot parameter in my case is `resume_offset=34816`. You still need to set a boot parameter for the partition to resume from. This will be the root partition (or whatever partition your swap file is located on) My parameters are now:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="no_console_suspend initcall_debug resume=/dev/mmcblk1p2 resume_offset=34816"
```

Where `/dev/mmcblk1p2` is my root partition (yours is more likely to be something like `/dev/sda2`).

During resume I saw the image loading successfully, but in my case (just an example - YMMVAPD) then some more drivers (`i2c_designware`) threw some errors and I got a complete system freeze on resume. Hibernation works if I unload those modules in addition to `brcmfmac`, but the system quickly becomes unusable without those modules. I therefore made a sort of script to unload the buggy modules and immediately reinsert them on resume:

```bsh
# remove buggy modules
modprobe -r brcmfmac i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core &&
# hibernate
echo disk > /sys/power/state
# reinsert
modprobe i2c_designware_core i2c_designware_platform brcmfmac
```

When I want to hibernate, I run `sudo bash script`. This works great.

---

### TL;DR

Use systemd, set a boot parameter for resume from swap, identify buggy drivers and unload them before initiating hibernation. If the system can't work for long without those modules or you need to unload several, it may be easier to use a simple script to initiate hibernation.

Comment: Where is that information from, that 2/5 of the RAM size might be enough, and under which circumstances? I have a user option in Gnome, "Hibernate" and it does seem to hibernate, but on waking up, it doesn't work properly. I have a swap partition of 8GB and 32GB RAM. That's not 2/5, but before creating a 32GB swap file (or partition) it'd be nice to know.

Comment: @cslotty I got that information from the Arch wiki IIRC - let me know if you do manage it please

Comment: Thanks, @Zanna. I found out that it's actually not hibernate, what I want, but suspend (S3/STR) - sry.

Comment: @cslotty no worries at all. In that case, swap is not your problem as it's not related.

Comment: Thanks, I needed a synthesis of this answer as well as the tip on disabling SecureBoot to make it work in the end.

Comment: @oligofren thanks for sharing that! I can't run Ubuntu at all with Secure Boot on, so that wouldn't be something I could catch.

Comment: With 18.04, the problem for me was that the installer has created a much too small swap partition in an encrypted volume. Enlarging it was the (troublesome) way to go, then hibernation worked out of the box, including UI buttons (in LXQt).

Comment: In my case, on Dell Latitude 5501 - Ubuntu 20.04, I need to set the swap by it's UUID to make the hibernate works. Then the `resume` option in grub also has to be UUID like `resume=UUID=your-swap-uuid-here`.

Comment: help with offset

Answer (score 67):

You can use

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

to check if hibernate works on your system (**this will hibernate your computer**).

If it does not work , check if your swap size is at least as large as your RAM.

To add the option to the settings menu, you can create a configuration file. Open a terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

It opens nano with an empty file. Copy the lines below and paste them into the nano window.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

Then save the changes and close nano and reboot the system to make Hibernate available appear on "Power options".

Reference: [How do I hibernate my computer?](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) in the official documentation for Ubuntu 16.04.

Hope it works. This worked for me after trying all other options.

Comment: We need a reboot after editing the file to make Hibernate available appear on "Power options".

Comment: 'sudo pm-hibernate' killed my system immediately without warning. You should tell people that's what's going to happen.

Comment: best answer  . This also working on 17.4 and 17.10 as well .

Comment: This answer combined with the one telling to add "resume=" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT did solve it for me - thx!

Comment: I have 17GB in my swap partition and 16GB of RAM, why is it not working? It seems to be hibernating because it takes forever to turn off the computer whereas if I do "shutdown" it turns off almost immediately. But when I turn my computer back on, everything's closed and I have to start over again. That's not hibernating at all. Why can't it be as simple as in Windows? I'd like some help if anyone has ideas about how I can get it to properly hibernate.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 16.04 **no reboot** was needed to make hibernate appear on Power options.

Answer (score 21):

I think, how to enable hibernate for 16.04 answer is known to all as described in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) (See below if you need the steps). But The things that need checking isn't thorough I think. At least, that's what I found.

#### Things to check

From my own tests, I've at least found one extra check that you should perform. I haven't found about it anywhere in the Internet.

Here are some checkings -

1. Check that you're not using any **btrfs** partitions. *Yes*. From my test, I found that if you have **btrfs** partitions, hibernate will not work. Removing or changing the partition type to `ext4` didn't help me. I needed to remove the `btrfs-tools` package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools
   ```

   You might want to check other new partition types which are not well tested. Without removing package, blacklisting the driver might also work, but I haven't tested that.
2. Also you need to check that you have a swap partition large enough to hold the content of RAM. If your RAM is 4 GB, swap should be at least 4 GB large ( You should allocate few more MB to be safe).

#### Steps to enable hibernate

It involves these steps

1. Create a file as root in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/enable-hibernate.pkla`

   ```
   sudo -i nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/enable-hibernate.pkla
   ```
2. Put these contents on that file

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes

   [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
3. Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>. Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
4. Restart the `polkitd` daemon

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart polkitd.service
   ```

It should enable hibernate.

Comment: Thanks, Anwar. I filed [bug #1619846](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1619846) and referred you your answer above. Any chance you could propose more exact changes/additions to that page in the official documentation?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'd propose this caveat. But, I'll need more testers verifying this. Will let you know later

Comment: Ok, let's talk more then.

Comment: I installed on a btrfs partition and purged `btrfs-tools` according to your instructions. Still can't hibernate.

Comment: @Oxwivi what other types of partitions were you mounting with `fstab` excluding ext3/4?

Comment: On disk there's only `vfat` for UEFI, and `btrfs` and `swap`. I'm actually suspecting it's due to the hardware (AMD laptop). I'm going to test this on another system with btrfs and get back at you.

Comment: @Oxwivi `btrfs` there!! you should try in same system without btrfs i think. If you can, make some room for another partition. install an Ubuntu there. enable hibernation. In `/etc/fstab` don't add any lines to mount the btrfs. Since it's a new installation, ubuntu won't recognize them any way (because, by default ubuntu doesn't know btrfs). now check if it works

Comment: Hibernation's worked on the other `btrfs` system I mentioned. And I also found that UEFI needs to be disabled for hibernation in Ubuntu. Congrats, you won the bounty!

Comment: @Oxwivi hibernation worked with `btrfs` mounting of with disabled `btrfs`?

Comment: I only purged `btrfs-tools` and changed nothing else.

Comment: @Gunnar Here Oxwivi verifying same thing. btrfs interrupted hibernation

Comment: note that on 18.10 btrfs is not a problem.

Answer (score 8):

### Secure Boot

(I asked a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd) asking for a focus on systemd-based replies, sharing my solution here for people following this question)

This solution comes from [Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/41118/f20-unable-to-hibernate-syspowerdisk-disabled/) topics (they made the switch to systemd a while ago so there's more material there).

In my case (fresh 16.04.1 install on a machine that always supported hibernation), calling the obsolete `sudo pm-hibernate` did not seem to do anything, and the up to date systemd approach, `systemctl hibernate`, would return:

```
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

It turns out that secure boot was the culprit: installing 16.04 you are asked what you want to do with it (which is a new thing as far as I can recall) and I kept it ON without giving it much thought.

On my machine with secure boot ON, `cat /sys/power/disk` answered:

```
 [disabled]
```

After reboot and disabling secure boot in the BIOS settings (these are machine-specific, but usually pretty straightforward) I tried a `cat /sys/power/disk` and got:

```
 [platform] shutdown reboot suspend
```

which looks better. And indeed calling `systemctl hibernate` results in a successful hibernate/thaw sequence.

Moreover, after that I could see hibernation available as an option in various places of the graphical interface, without the need of any `polkit` hack. So it seems that `systemd` was actually guessing from `/sys/power/disk` that the system was not able to hibernate.

Comment: I did exactly what you have explained here. But after I execute "systemctl hibernate" command the screen got black for 3 seconds then the desktop went back with all my opened programs just like before I executed the command.  When I executed the command "cat /sys/power/disk"... it shown me this text: "[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume" which it's similar to the result when you executed the same from your side but the last text: "test_resume". Do you have an idea what I could try to solve my problem ?

Comment: Not too sure, looks like hibernation does not work out of the box on your hardware, which is why it is disabled by default as others pointed out.
You might want to start a separate question about your specific issue.

Comment: Only half-working for me. Hibernates but instead of waking up from hibernation, goes to normal boot, then gets stuck forever until a hard physical shutdown.

Answer (score 8):

Trying to put the system into hibernate (deep sleep where RAM is written to disk), generated the following error

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

The following steps resolve the issue (Tested on Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th Gen, Ubuntu 19.10). Most of them are borrowed from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946).

1. Turn off Secure Boot in BIOS.
2. Set "Sleep State" to Linux in BIOS. This options was originally named "Modern Standby" in my BIOS and I had to turn if off, but after a BIOS name the name was changed to "Sleep State".
3. Create a swap file equal or bigger than RAM. Several steps are involved here which are as follows.

   a. Turn off swap.

   ```
   $  sudo swapoff -a
   ```

   b. Create a file bigger or equal to the RAM. Mine is 16GB, so:

   ```
   $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=16

   16+0 records in
   16+0 records out
   17179869184 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 19.3685 s, 887 MB/s
   ```

   c. Set the right permissions for the file:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```

   d. Make the file as swap:

   ```
   $ sudo mkswap /swapfile

   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 16 GiB (17179865088 bytes)
   no label, UUID=3b2e6f0c-ce12-4a84-9044-d99bfba059ea
   ```

   e. Turn on swap and check if it is set properly:

   ```
   $ sudo swapon /swapfile
   $ cat /proc/swaps

   Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
   /swapfile                               file        16777212    0   -2
   ```

   f. In order to make the swap be loaded after reboot, we have to add it to `/etc/fstab`. Thus run the following command to open the file:

   ```
   $ sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   And update it by adding the last line like below. Note that I have also commented my original swap as I don't need it.

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   # /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
   UUID=d265e7c4-1a4f-49c4-af29-fea2543490d7 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
   # /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
   UUID=0004-FB5F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
   #/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
   /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
   ```

   g. Do a reboot and run this command to see if the swap shows up:

   ```
   cat /proc/swaps

   Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
   /swapfile                               file        16777212    0   -2
   ```
4. Now, it's time to update the grub.
   a. Run this command to open grub:

   ```
   $ sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   b. Find where root is mounted by running the following command.

   ```
   $ mount | grep " / "

   /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
   ```

   c. So mind is mounted on `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`. Find the UUID of this location by running:

   ```
   $ sudo blkid
   /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: UUID="AZrE57-dlNc-BiUr-RrTF-SdT2-luVK-vrliNq" TYPE="LVM2_member"
   /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="2331fe68-3e7a-4937-9cfa-74fc7a4b79f6" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="0004-FB5F" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="09813156-6b7a-4fc2-b644-a8c6b7d40abf"
   /dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="d265e7c4-1a4f-49c4-af29-fea2543490d7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="64f5da2f-71d3-4f02-9b1e-3e12d7f6c445"
   /dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="201acba5-ff20-46ee-9000-34efefef3fbe" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="16858e70-eb08-4de8-b944-50689cad9d9f"
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="ST64GB" UUID="624AB7B308FE9F38" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos"
   /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="af3b29a2-ba6b-44de-89dd-072f4233aaf9" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   The UUID in this case is `2331fe68-3e7a-4937-9cfa-74fc7a4b79f6`. Keep this UUID.
   d. Next, we need to find the offset of the swap file. Run this command:

   ```
   $ sudo filefrag -v /swapfile

   Filesystem type is: ef53
   File size of /swapfile is 17179869184 (4194304 blocks of 4096 bytes)
   ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
     0:        0..   32767:     835584..    868351:  32768:            
     1:    32768..   49151:     868352..    884735:  16384:            
     2:    49152..   81919:     886784..    919551:  32768:  
     ...
   ```

   We look for the pysical_offset of the first block. In the above case, it will is `835584`. Keep this number too.
   e. We need to update the grub now. Run the following command:

   ```
   $ sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Update with the following content. We update `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0`.

   ```
   # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
   # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
   # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
   #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=2331fe68-3e7a-4937-9cfa-74fc7a4b79f6 resume_offset=835584"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

   # Avoiding grub to show up in boot when resuming from hibernation
   GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
   ```

   f. Once the grub file is updated, run this command:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```

That should be it. Now you can put the system into hibernation by running

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 6):

For me, it works to install `hibernate` package, reboot and then run `sudo hibernate-disk`. I am sure it is possible to add it to menu, but is not worth the time for me.

Comment: This didn't help me. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with dual boot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Answer (score 6):

This instruction worked for my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

1. `sudo apt install hibernate` It will install hibernate and other dependencies which are needed to hibernate
2. `grep swap /etc/fstab` (fing UUID)
3. `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` 
   At the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" add UUID of swap. The line looks like this GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID of swap"
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Restart, and after restart `sudo systemctl hibernate`. If everything works ok add menu entry's.
6. `sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` 
   now paste this:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

copied from https://askubuntu.com/a/819891/712203

7. Restart the computer
8. Install https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/

Comment: instead of adding a fixed value to `/etc/default/grub` consider updating the initramfs using `update-initramfs -u -k all` and look for a message like `The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-0`. This will automatically set the resume device.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04! Note that if it is the first time you use a gnome extension, you will need to install a browser extension and a connector. This is explained in the extension link at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on my own comment to kelvinelove's answer, the file he suggests editing did not exist on my system (fresh Ubuntu 16.04). Instead, I did this:

1. `sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`
2. Look for these sections (they are right by each other):

   > [Disable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:*
   >   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=no
   >
   > [Disable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:*
   >   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;
   >   ResultActive=no
3. Change **ResultActive=no** to **ResultActive=yes** for both of them.
4. Press *Ctrl + O* to save the file.
5. Reboot your computer
6. The *Hibernate* option is now available in your power menus.

**EDIT: Gunnar pointed out that this file gets overwritten if a certain package gets updated, so depending on your intentions it is most likely not the best solution.**

*Source: http://www.zedt.eu/tech/linux/enable-hibernation-xubuntu-16-04/*

Comment: The file in `/etc` is not supposed to exists by default. It's a configuration file which you create. Editing a package owned file, as you suggest above, is bad advice, since it will be overwritten at next package update.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson If that's the case I would argue that it should be stated that it might not exist. I expect more from a top rated Ask Ubuntu answer than a "copy/paste this command"->"type this" -style answer that lacks any kind of verification of whether you are doing the right thing (other than checking if it worked). What if someone finds that answer in a couple of years, but is afraid of trying it since the file is empty, and the instructions clearly state to add to the file, implying that it exists? Nonetheless, I appreciate the information, will add it to the answer for completion.

Comment: Fair point; I edited NirajW's answer with that clarification. It should be noted that the original source of info at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) talks about _creation_.

Comment: This is perfect you saved me brother :)

Answer (score 3):

First, I do recommend that you test if your machine supports hibernation, because the reason why hibernation is disabled by default is because it sometimes has unpleasant results on some machines. Test your machine by opening the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then typing `sudo pm-hibernate`

Your machine should hibernate. Wake your machine up after hibernation and observe if it misbehaves or if it acts normally. 
If you experience any abnormality after the hibernation, then I advise you don't continue with the following procedure. However, if it works just fine, continue to activate hibernation by doing this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Edit the opened file and add this lines:

```
[Re-enable hibernation]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After this, restart your machine, and after logging in, you should see a hibernation option added on the power menu, on the top right settings corner.

Comment: I have thinkpad -E550 and it has no problem with hibernation when my OS is ubuntu 15.1 or windows8.1 . but using ubuntu 16.04 , when i use the command "sudo pm-hibernate" , it does not completely hibernate and just the screen goes black and the machine is still on.

Comment: In my case, the command does nothing at all. The terminal goes to the newline and awaits next command i.e. previous command has been executed. But it does nothing `at all`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 16.04. The Hibernate option do not come up and stay disable in Settings -> Power, anything else?

Comment: Editing the already existing policy is better: http://www.zedt.eu/tech/linux/enable-hibernation-xubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Incomplete contents in `com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. See answer posted by NirajW.

Comment: @fgblomqvist: No, it's not, since such edits will be overwritten at next package update.

Answer (score 3):

There are some very good resources here to help you sort out some of the more common hibernate issues under Ubuntu.

In my case, running Ubuntu 16.10 on a Lenovo u300s, in order for hibernate to work correctly I had to do the following:

- Create an appropriately-sized swap file (I typically set for ~1x in
  size, but I've heard up to 1.6x and 2x)
- Edit `/etc/default/grub` to include the following line:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet pci=nomsi RESUME=UUID=92781adb-f2a6-4f15-88fc-e1ce801291dd"
  ```

The RESUME refers to your specific swap file UUID. In particular, on my machine setting `pci=nomsi` was the key.

Best of luck!

Comment: Is grub case insensitive? Why use RESUME?

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually enable it with a little effort. It's been disabled by default.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

Then, if it doesn't work, it's might be a 4.4.0 kernel issue, and you might have to upgrade kernel.

Comment: The answer referes to 14.04, while the question is about 16.04.

Comment: This works in 16.04 too!