# Enable Hibernate option on setting menu in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

How to enable the hibernation option on system menu in Ubuntu 14.04 just like windows.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Comment: It should be noted that any answers relating to systemd (`systemctl`) on the linked post will not work in 14.04

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your SWAP area is larger than your RAM. You can give it a try by entering

> sudo pm-hibernate

If everything looks good then you can dig into it.

To enable the hibernation option.
[See answer in the link](https://askubuntu.com/a/819891/650960)

Comment: My swap memory is 4.19 Gib ie 4.49GB larger than my RAM(4GB) but instead your link doesn't help me out from this problem