# How to enable hibernation on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, 18.04, hibernate

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo P50

I've tried to hibernate from the command line with `sudo systemctl hibernate` and what I get is

> Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported

And also  `cat /sys/power/disk`

> [platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume

Some additional information:

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       15656592     4578236     8186108      183960     2892248    12247168
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

```
swapon --summary
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not support hibernate on all hardware.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: One obvious problem is your swap space is not as big as your memory. Your swap has to be at least the same size, so your in-memory processes can be saved somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on my X1 Carbon 7th Gen. 
I did the following to enable the hibernation:

1. Turn off Secure Boot in BIOS.
2. Turn off "Modern Standby" in BIOS.
3. Create a swap file bigger than my RAM.
4. Update the grub using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/821122/889735).