# Hibernation not working in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hibernate

Linux/Ubuntu rookie here, so please be gentle :)

I've installed Ubuntu 18 in my laptop and I'm trying to configure hibernation. I've tried to follow [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/) [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04), but still without any results...

I've changed my partition so that it's 11GB (I've tried to follow what was written [here](https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/)):

```
sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   11G   0B   -2
```

If I try to use the pm-hibernate, nothing happens...

Looking at the logs, I can see these entries:

```
22:00:47 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
22:00:47 systemd: Failed to start Hibernate.
22:00:47 kernel: PM: Cannot get swap writer
22:00:42 kernel: wlp2s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
21:57:49 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
21:57:49 systemd: Failed to start Hibernate.
21:57:49 kernel: PM: Cannot get swap writer
21:57:44 kernel: wlp2s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
21:55:44 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
21:55:44 systemd: Failed to start Hibernate.
21:55:44 kernel: PM: Swap header not found!
21:55:35 kernel: wlp2s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
21:55:17 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
21:55:16 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
21:55:10 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
21:55:07 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
21:55:03 kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
```

It's obvious there's some sort of problem when hibernation starts, but I really don't knohich the machine state is written to disk, eitw what's wrong...

Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score -1):

To my information, hibernation to a swap *file* does not work, and might never do.

However, suspending to the swapfile usually works. The problem should usually just happen when you try to resume from it.

The file system is not mounted at the point Linux tries to find the swap to resume from, and thus will fail to do so.