# Laptop Hibernate on Lid Closed

Tags: laptop, hibernate, mint

My laptop (Ryzen HP Envy) keeps running out of power while the lid is closed. My suspicion is that the laptop isn't saving the state to the HDD (Hibernate) and instead saving it to RAM and still consuming power.

Could someone suggest a way to force the laptop to go into hibernation while the lid is closed?

I'm using **Linux mint** so I'm not sure which is the default.

Also, if anyone has any opinion on using save-to-hdd instead of save-to-ram I'd love to hear it, I just imagine it depends on how you personally use the laptop.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out.

[Go here to try and set up hibernate for your device.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Once it is set up and if it works for you, at least on Linux Mint, you can go to **Power Management** and find a **When the lid is closed** option under the **Power** tab. You can now change what happens to your device when the lid closes while on A/C power and off.