# Swap partition is larger than Ram but Hibernate not working

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

I'm running on 
ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS + 8GB Ram + 17GB Swap partition ( HP-2000 Laptop )

even my swap partition larger than RAM, when i'm trying to execute

`sudo systemctl hibernate` 
or 
`sudo pm-hibernate`

these commands dosen't work.
and can't enable hibernate as discuss in following thred

[How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
sudo apt-get install hibernate
```

After that just type in terminal `sudo hibernate` This way work for me