# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Attempting to change lid close action to "hibernate" broke everythinig

Tags: power-management, hibernate, recovery-mode

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS laptop that dual-boots with Windows 10. I was fed up with all of my programs quitting every time I close the lid, so I attempted to change the lid close action to "hibernate," like my Windows side does. I followed the guide here: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
Immediately after running the Systemd restart command, I was kicked to the login screen, and was unable to login again: I kept returning to the login screen after each attempt. When I powered off the laptop and attempted to boot, Ubuntu entered emergency mode. I thought perhaps reverting my changes in /etc/systemd/logind.conf would fix the issue, but it still persists. Does anyone know how I can make my computer work properly again? I can provide any additional information necessary.

[image: Here's a photo of the first bit of text that shows up on screen before the screen completely fills with scrolling text.]

Comment: Did you test hibernation prior to changing the lid close action?

Comment: I did not. This may have been stupid of me, but I assumed that it would work, given that hibernation works on the Windows side of my machine. I re-commented the line in logind.conf, though, and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Hibernate is tricky, and I recent;y have stopped using it because of *repeated corruption* of my hard drive.  Try this - load up a live USB of Ubuntu, boot it on your computer and run `fsck -f /dev/sdxx` to check the integrity of your disks.

Comment: I will do that. However, I should stress that I never actually attempted to hibernate Ubuntu at all. This problem started as soon as I ran the command to reload Systemd - it logged me out and wouldn't let me log in again, then went into emergency mode after I tried restarting.

Comment: K - I don't think that the changes to logind.conf should have caused an issue - I tried reloading as mentioned in the article once (for another purpose) but never again.  Can you append your question with the text of  `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`?

Comment: Also, this article [https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122](https://askubuntu.com/a/821122/283721) was a good resource for setting up hibernation - the later section of the answer I linked to discusses using a swapfile instead of a swap partition.  I also specifically needed to add a RESUME_DELAY parameter to Grub.

Comment: logind.conf is all comments, except for one line: [login].
The command "systemctl restart systemd-logind.service" is what started this problem.

Comment: That's what mine shows as well (after I removed the hibernate related stuff).  This is part of what makes me lean towards a bit of corruption on the disk.  My experience with hibernation was mostly positive, but after four or five times fixing the disk I gave up.  No problems since.

Comment: How can it have corrupted my disk when I never actually tried to hibernate? It was the systemctl restart command that first kicked me to the login screen and all, not closing my lid or anything like that.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't... but using the command results in an immediate termination of Xorg, and who knows what else.  It feels much cleaner to reboot.

Comment: I ran fsck from a USB, and it says my Ubuntu partition is clean. It's still going into emergency mode though.

Comment: `fsck` or `fsck -f`?  The `-f` option indicates that fsck should perform a check *even if* the superblock thinks the system is clean. See `man e2fsck`

Comment: I ran it again with -f, and got the message "285102/3735552 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 4887098/14934016 blocks." Ubuntu still boots to emergency mode.

Comment: K - the next step of items to check is [https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: No effect. I wasn't able to log in at all (ctrl-alt-f3 resulted in an infinite blinking cursor), and none of the other things had any effect. I'm appending a photo of the first few lines of console before the system goes fully into emergency mode.

Comment: I'm just gonna take an image of the partition and wipe it.

Comment: Might be easiest.  If you can boot to a live USB, you can copy files from your partitions to a backup device.