# Need Hibernation and Suspend on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, hibernate, 19.04

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.04 on an Asus Vivomax laptop. It has Intel Celeron N3350 and nvidia GF 810m running in Prime mode. Suspend just turns off the screen for a moment and then takes me to the lockscreen -  and for some reason the desktop image fails to load after that. As for hibernation, I couldnt find any button or setting to enable it. When I try "sudo pm-hibernate" it says there is no swap partition, even though I created and turned on a swap partition in gparted.. can you help me plz? I need the ability to at least suspend my leptop, otherwise I will be forced to use another OS... thanks in advance!

EDIT: After updating to the latest BIOS (My model number is ASUS X541NC) suspend works, but "sudo pm-hibernate" still gives the "Swap header not found" error

Comment: Please edit your question, and include the output of `df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs`

Comment: You may also find reading through [https://askubuntu.com/a/821122/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/821122/283721) and [http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/) to be useful