# "systemctl suspend" vs "systemctl hibernate" Permission

Tags: 18.04, permissions, suspend, power-management, hibernate

When I type in `systemctl suspend` in the terminal, my pc goes into sleep mode with no issue. However, when I type in `systemctl hibernate`, it firsts prints this error

```
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Access denied
```

And then asks for password saying hibernate.target needs authentication.

So, any idea how I can have `systemctl hibernate` have the same behavior as `systemctl suspend`?

Comment: Did you try with root? I get the same error, and wonder why. It adds to the error: Failed to start hibernate.target: Unit hibernate.target is masked.

Comment: I tried with root back then. Here are the instructions I followed to make it work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1197965/889735.

Comment: Related: [systemctl suspend, Call to Suspend failed: Access denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749708/209677). keyword: polkit

Answer (score 0):

I got same message with fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. It's probably because you need privileges to execute `systemctl hibernate`. To solve it, I did:

```
    sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/hibernate
```

and added following line:

```
    %adm    ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl hibernate, /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
```

Note: My user is member of group adm. Alternatively you can add new group, add all relevant users to that group and replace `%adm` by `%<your-group>`.

I'm not sure this is best practice but it solved the issue for me.

Furthermore you need swap space (swap file or swap partition) of minimum size of your RAM in order to hibernate you computer.

EDIT: added -f parameter for visudo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added these two lines to the same file to enable running it: `Cmnd_Alias HIBERNATE_SVC = /bin/systemctl hibernate`

`%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: HIBERNATE_SVC`

I still need to run it with `sudo` though but it does not need a password.