# /SWAPFILE hibernate on DELL XPS Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: grub2, dell, hibernate, xps

I have Dell XPS which I bought with linux configured.  It uses /swapfile.  I would like to enable hibernate.  Have tried method described in [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)  but I just get a (slightly damaged - chrome crashes and must be started twice - at which point it offers to restore) clean reboot.
I changed /etc/default/grub to contain

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="no_console_suspend initcall_debug resume=/dev/nvme0n1p3 resume_offset=34816"

(34816 was appropriate for me as well as the example)

dmesg seems OK

Any ideas?
--Len

Comment: How big is your RAM? SWAP? Install the `pm-tools` package, do `dpkg -L pm-tools`. Read the `man`  pages, all the UPPERCASE filenames, and anything else that looks good.

Comment: pm-tools is not in ubuntu repository.  RAM 16GB, SWAP 32GB